# How to make a textbox blurred/disabled on focus

Tags: javascript, html, focus, blur

How do I go about disabling/blurring a textbox when it gains focus using JavaScript, without using `disabled` or `readonly`?

Comment: disabling and blurring are 2 totally different things. what do you want exactly? And it sounds terrible that you want to disable/blur once an element gains focus. if you can explain why you'd want that. would help too

Comment: Why cant you use `disabled` and `readonly` attributes?

Comment: my assignment requires me to do so. the textbox should be blurred each time it gains focus

Comment: So do you want the textbox to be blurred *and* disabled, or only blurred? As @NickTimmer said, those are two different things.

Comment: its more of blurred actually. onfocus=this.blur(); solved my issue

Comment: Can you post the code that solved your issue? Just for the rest of us who were confused what you were exactly trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what youre trying to achieve based on the question:

```js
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');

fname.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.blur();
})
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
```

Comment: OP said he can't (or doesn't want to) use `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a CSS class for your textbox. For example:

HTML:

```
class="blurTextbox"
```

CSS:

```css
.blurTextbox:focus{
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

You can look up other desired blur effects on Google; I think you´ll find some nice ones.

Comment: Workable solution, but OP asked for a way to do it using JavaScript (for whatever reason).